# Visualizing point cloud with open3d

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I'm using the following code to visualize the point cloud.

```
import open3d as o3d
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("assets/pcd.ply")

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd],lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/pointcloud.py", line 5, in <module>
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd],lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, -0.4])
TypeError: draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (geometry_list: List[open3d.open3d_pybind.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50, point_show_normal: bool = False, mesh_show_wireframe: bool = False, mesh_show_back_face: bool = False) -> None

Invoked with: [geometry::PointCloud with 677248 points.]; kwargs: lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, -0.4]
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `lookat` parameter in the draw_geometries function. You can simply visualize without that parameter

The deeper reason for the error is caused by the mismatched version open3D. For the lastest version, some parameters and functions have been modified.

Comment: Is there no way to change the starting location of the camera, then? That's pretty crazy to me that this was just dropped

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on Open3D version 3 years ago, but there is draw_geometries variant which accepts `lookat` variable now. The pybind code to generate python bindings is [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/master/cpp/pybind/visualization/utility.cpp#L147) **but notice that it is necessary to pass all 4 variables**: `front, lookat, up, zoom`.

```
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(
            geometries,
            front=[0.4699189535486108, -0.62764022425775134, 0.62068021233921933],
            lookat=[ -0.97243714332580566, -0.1751408576965332, 0.51464511454105377 ],
            up=[ -0.36828927493940194, 0.49961995188329117, 0.78405542766104697 ],
            zoom=0.15999999999999961,
        )
```

Tip - Above values are first generated by executing  `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(geometries,)`, setting camera position and then pressing `Ctrl + C` which copies View control settings. A sample output is:-

```
{
    "class_name" : "ViewTrajectory",
    "interval" : 29,
    "is_loop" : false,
    "trajectory" : 
    [
        {
            "boundingbox_max" : [ 3.0492053031921387, 6.549717903137207, 1.4599999189376831 ],
            "boundingbox_min" : [ -4.99407958984375, -6.8999996185302734, -0.43070968985557556 ],
            "field_of_view" : 60.0,
            "front" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
            "lookat" : [ -0.97243714332580566, -0.1751408576965332, 0.51464511454105377 ],
            "up" : [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
            "zoom" : 0.69999999999999996
        }
    ],
    "version_major" : 1,
    "version_minor" : 0
}
```