# Python: TypeError: draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, numpy, open3d

I am trying to implement an Open3D model to generate point cloud from a monocular depth map.

Referred to this YouTube video - https://youtu.be/teHGdlGhQZo

OpenCV == 4.4.0

Open3D == 0.15.1

BGR Image - 640x480x3

Depth Image - 640x480x3

Code -

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os 
import sys
import cv2
import open3d_tutorial as o3dtut
o3dtut.interactive = not "CI" in os.environ

color_raw = o3d.io.read_image('colorImg.jpg')
depth_raw = o3d.io.read_image('depthImg2.png')

rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(color_raw,depth_raw)
print(rgbd_image)
camera_intrinsic = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
        o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsicParameters.PrimeSenseDefault)

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, camera_intrinsic)
pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd], zoom=0.5)
```

Error Message -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18872/3179634559.py in <module>
      1 pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
----> 2 o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd], zoom=0.5)

TypeError: draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (geometry_list: List[open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50, point_show_normal: bool = False, mesh_show_wireframe: bool = False, mesh_show_back_face: bool = False) -> None
    2. (geometry_list: List[open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50, point_show_normal: bool = False, mesh_show_wireframe: bool = False, mesh_show_back_face: bool = False, lookat: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[3, 1]], up: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[3, 1]], front: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[3, 1]], zoom: float) -> None

Invoked with: [PointCloud with 306097 points.]; kwargs: zoom=0.5
```

Already Tried -

Tried changing the Open3D version from 0.16 -> 0.15

Tried twitching the dimensions of the images.

Comment: OpenCV is not actually used in this code. I've removed the tag. do not tag technologies that don't contribute to the issue. please review [mre], also take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: Hi OpenCV is actually used to resize images if not present in desired shape

Comment: the traceback does not indicate any involvement of OpenCV. if you provide images that are in the desired shape already, it wouldn't try to use OpenCV at all. in any case, do not tag technologies that aren't absolutely required to reproduce the issue. please review [mre] carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the zoom parameter, just checked that draw_geometries isn't currently supporting this.
Remove it and your code will work just fine.

Comment: While this is fastest solution to get code working, `zoom` param is supported by `draw_geometries`. The problem is for `zoom` to work, you need to also specify `lookat`, `up`, and `front` arguments to draw_geometries. See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76828436/1874627